# HAML-helpers (tab_up) do not work

Tags: ruby, haml, helper

I am trying to use the tab_up and tab_down haml-helper. My understanding is, that after tab_up the next line should indented.

This haml code...

```
%h1 foo
- tab_up
%p bar
- tab_down
%strong baz
```

should produce this html...

```
<h1>foo</h1>
  <p>bar</p>
<strong>baz</strong>
```

but in my case it produces...

```
<h1>foo</h1>
<p>bar</p>
<strong>baz</strong>
```

Changing the haml to...

```
%h1 foo
= tab_up
%p bar
= tab_down
%strong baz
```

leads to...

```
<h1>foo</h1>
1
<p>bar</p>
0
<strong>baz</strong>
```

So it seems, the counting of the tabs is running correctly, but they are not considered when the output is created. Other haml-helpers running well. Do I have to take anything else into account when using tab_up and tab_down?

I am using
Rails 3.2.8, 
Ruby 1.9.2, 
Windows7

Comment: I have the same problem. Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you looking to "see" the html?  I just tested this for me and it works correctly in the page source. If you look at it in firebug or a similar tool, it will not show the indentation.